# How to organize Kubernete cluster on GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Let's say I have two projects: a `jenkins ci` and a `small application` (deployed with jenkins). Should I put them in the same cluster ?

This is the commands I run inside Jenkinsfile to deploy the app:

```
sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/")
sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/production/")
```

In case it's better to put them in separate cluster, how can I use `kubectl` to apply the resources inside another cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If want to use 2 cluster then put both cluster config in 2 different kube config and then call these file while executing kubectl, like below
kubectl --kubeconfig  --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/"

Comment: Would suggest to use single cluster, with different namespace.